# Symfony 3.1: error when requesting app_dev.php or app.php

Tags: apache, symfony

Im getting this when requesting `sorial/app_dev.php`:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /app_dev.php/ was not found on this server.
```

And when requesting `sorial/app.php`:

> unregister(); $apcLoader->register(true); */ $kernel = new
>   AppKernel('prod', false); $kernel->loadClassCache(); //$kernel = new
>   AppCache($kernel); // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the
>   method in your front controller instead of relying on the
>   configuration parameter
>   //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request =
>   Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request);
>   $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Im on Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4

**EDIT:** This is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sorial
    #ServerAlias sorial.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sorial/web
        DirectoryIndex app.php
    #SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD jander
    <Directory /var/www/sorial/web/>
        # Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
        Require all granted
        FallbackResource /index.php
        # BEGIN EXPIRES
        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
        </IfModule>
        # END EXPIRES
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my document root is at `/var/www/sorial/web`.

The truth is I have the same problem for the rest of my sites. The problem started when I try to disable/enable `env_mod` using `a2dismod env`, since when adding the variable `SetEnv` (as you can see in my virtual host) I was getting

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

when restarting apache.

Comment: Have you tried to run you app with this command: php bin/console server:run?

Comment: Can you show us your Apache VirtualHost or DirectoryRoot configuration? I'm wondering what did you specify for the web directory?

Comment: @Giovani thanks, that is working, but I prefer to use Apache.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I edited my question.

Comment: Why if your VH is named `sorial` you try to get `my_site/app_dev.php` instead of `sorial/app_dev.php` ? or it's a typo?

Comment: @Yonel yes, it is a typo, sorry. Now it is corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally **solved my problem** installing php5 and libapache2-mod-php5 like this: `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

Answer (score 2):

> I finally solved my problem installing php5 and libapache2-mod-php5 like this: sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 — [@ziiweb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006045/934739)

The error you received is usually caused by missing or corrupted configuration files.

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

The `journalctl` command [can be used](https://askubuntu.com/a/662866) to see more details.

```
$ journalctl | tail
AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain-wsf.lan.conf
```

You can also do an Apache configuration test.

```
$ apachectl configtest
Syntax OK

$ sed -i 's/SetEnv/SetEnvFoobar/' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf

$ apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf:
Invalid command 'SetEnvFoobar', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The `apachectl graceful` command is also very useful. It restarts Apache, **but runs a configtest first *"before initiating the restart to make sure Apache doesn't die."***

> `apachectl graceful`
>
> Gracefully restarts the Apache `httpd` daemon. If the daemon is not running, it is started. This differs from a normal restart in that currently open connections are not aborted. A side effect is that old log files will not be closed immediately. This means that if used in a log rotation script, a substantial delay may be necessary to ensure that the old log files are closed before processing them. This command automatically checks the configuration files as in `configtest` before initiating the restart to make sure Apache doesn't die. This is equivalent to `apachectl -k graceful`
>
> — [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html)

Reinstalling software can work because it will fix any missing configurations files.

```
$ apt-get install --resinstall libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Another alternative, [noted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/746206), is to purge and then install. **It is very important to know however, that `purge` is a destructive command meaning it will delete all existing configurations files. This is pretty much the equivalent of a fresh install.**

```
$ apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5 php5
$ apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same problem using Debian with apache as server. Try to replace your **.htaccess** inside **web** directory and clear the cache.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
```

And this should be your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName sorial

 DocumentRoot /var/www/sorial/web
 <Directory /var/www/sorial/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in my config I'm using .htaccess files, and I see you've commented out the Options line. I wonder if you had a reason for that?

If not, I would suggest uncommenting it like so:

```
<Directory /var/www/sorial/web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

See if that works.

Comment: @Thanks, but the problem is still there. Well maybe now the text shown when requesting the prod environment is different.. I edited my question.