# Generate new symfony project: permissions for directories created

Tags: symfony

I have just generated a new Symfony 3 project, and I have realized that directories has `755` permissions. For examppe, in project root directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 oct  3 21:14 web
drwxr-xr-x 15 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 var
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 tests
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 src
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 me me  4096 oct 10 12:08 app
```

In case my current `umask` is `0002` so when I create a new directory (`mkdir`) at `/tmp` for example, the permissions are `775`.

So why the Symfony directories has `755`? Why did they choose that? Is this configurable?

Im on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: First, do you plan to respond to [your question posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927647/symfony-3-1-error-when-requesting-app-dev-php-or-app-php) 2 days ago? Secondly, is there a problem with those permissions? I suspect you'll need to run `chown -R apache:apache` on your directory, since I doubt that `me` is the http group:user.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Thanks for remind me. Second, I don't have any problem with those permissions, but Im curious about it. When I create a project a run `symfony new project` from my user (me), Is there any problem about that? Why the user:group should be the apache user (`www-data`)?